# Bernstein algorithms - Exception user unhandled

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement the Bernstein polynomials algorithm in C#.

The algorithm is this one:

[image]

k goes from 0 to n while n can go from 0 to infinite (in my code n goes from 0 to a value which will be 3)

in my code n is named as p;
in my code t is named as i-1.

This is my code:

```
        double nchoosek = 1;
        double ti = 0;  // Change of basis
        double tf = 1;  // Change of basis
        double tt;
        double Bernst;
        List<double> Bernste = new List<double>();
        List<List<double>> Bernstein = new List<List<double>>();

        for (int i =1;  i <= p+1; i++)
        {
            nchoosek *= p - (p - i);
            nchoosek /= i;
            for (double t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.05)
            {
                tt = (t - ti) / (tf - ti);  // Change of basis
                Bernst = nchoosek * Math.Pow((1 - tt), (p - (i-1))) * Math.Pow((tt), (i-1));
                Bernste.Add(Bernst);
            }
            Bernstein[i] = Bernste;
        }
```

Could somebody tell me why it goes out of range?

I noticed that if in the end I change `Bernstein[i] = Bernste` with `Bernstein.Add(Bernste)` the code works but it gives me the latest Bernste numbers of the cycle.

Comment: Your `Bernstein` collection is completely empty. So you cannot do `[i]` on it.

Comment: (p - (i-1) eventually becomes a large negative numbers.  So you are raising to a very  large number and getting a overflow.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to access element on `Bernstein` list by index (I think you are trying to add an element).

Just use `Add`:

```
Bernstein.Add(Bernste);
```

just like you did few lines before.

IMPORTANT: just before inner loop you need to initialize `Bernste` list again, so you don't add another elements over and over:

```
for (int i =1;  i <= p+1; i++)
{
  nchoosek *= p - (p - i);
  nchoosek /= i;
  Bernste = new List<double>();
  for (double t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.05)
  {
    tt = (t - ti) / (tf - ti);  // Change of basis
    Bernst = nchoosek * Math.Pow((1 - tt), (p - (i-1))) * Math.Pow((tt), (i-1));
    Bernste.Add(Bernst);
  }
  Bernstein.Add(Bernste);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Michał Turczyn thanks for the clarification. What I don't understand is how to put the Bernste values into the different lists of Bernstein. I mean.. let's suppose we have p=3 in my code. After the first iteration with i=1 I want to put all the values calculated in Bernste into Bernstein[1]. When the iteration i=2 occurs I want to put all the values calculated in Bernste into Bernstein[2] and so on..

Comment: @RobertoRuggeri just use Add method on Berstein list, as suggested :) run it and see for yourself :)

Comment: if I add Bernste = new List<double>(); where you suggested me to do, my final Bernstein list is empty. If I don't add it and I use .Add in Bernstein list I receive 4 lists with the same values. :(